# Fill the foundation cinder block?

Tags: concrete, doors, slab

Removed carpet from a lower level walkout in a 1985 Minneapolis house and found the patio door is set on the cinder block foundation wall. Planning on installing LVP. Should I clean the detritus and fill the cinder block with cement, sand and cement, expanding foam insulation?  The holes are currently varying depth, 1-6inches generally, possibly deeper when cleaned. Or should I end the flooring prior to the cinder block and look for a wide transition piece and not worry about filling?

[image: door]

Comment: I'd be tempted to vacuum 'em out best possible, and fill with the LOW EXPANDING foam.  (The  normal stuff that expands alot may push the door frame straight up.. you surely don't want that!)

Comment: I would even it with self leveling concrete/underlayment.  Foam may deteriorate or sag with foot traffic on it.

Comment: I do see the holes there, but they don't look all that large. Could you add a better lit, close up picture with a tape measure to show how big they are? I'm not experienced in laying LVP flooring, but I wouldn't think that small a hole would be a serious issue that close to the door frame where people aren't likely to step on it (most people would step on the door frame itself or over the whole thing, but not put their foot that close to the sill).

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  After finding out a coworker is ex-home construction and discussing with him,  going to go clean out the really shallow holes a little bit and fill with concrete (thin enough to pour with some ease.)  Usually (here at least) they are filled in before installing the door, which is why we hadn't seen this before.